# Possible to assign User Admin Role for B2C Tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are looking at Azure AD B2C and wish to use the Azure AD Graph API to create users using the User Admin Role. For security reasons wish  want to assign this permission for the Azure AD B2C Tenant only and not the Azure AD Tenant. I have not found an example of this so wish to confirm is it possible?

Cheers,
Lastbuilders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate Azure AD tenant and Azure AD B2C tenant.
It is all the B2C tenant. 
So an application having access via Graph API means access to everything in the tenant.

Comment: Thanks juunas, I have been looking at this example and note the app registration needs to be at the AD directory level rather than the b2c tenant level to assign the directory readwrite permissions. Will this not also give this permission at the directory level as well as the  b2c tenant level?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet?tabs=applications.

Comment: Applications are different in B2C yes. To get graph API access, the app needs to be registered through the AAD app registrations panel. Permissions given to those apps apply to the directory/tenant. This includes users for example.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  This is what I thought. I was hoping there was an option to have more fine grained control to enable CRUD for users in the B2C tenant and not at the directory level as I do not believe we will be able to get those permissions at the directory level which is also used as our corporate AD.

Comment: Yeah, users in the tenant are all in one big set. No matter if you go to Users tab in AAD management blade or B2C management, you'll see the same users.